# Why Strange Formatting For My Caption

Tags: graphics, floats, captions

I am trying to include an image with a nice caption below it. I have the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{ampicillin_timeline}
  \caption{Illustration of ampicillin inhibiting bacterial formation.
    (https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Penicillin\_spheroplast\_%
    generation.svg)}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The image shows up fine but the caption underneath looks absolutely horrible:

[image: ugly caption]

How can I make the caption actually look good?

Comment: Use the `url` package to format the link and allow it to break URLs across lines. Else, set the caption `\raggedright` or in a box of smaller width. (`caption` is a good package if you prefer the second option.) Or cite your sources, which is how I generally handle this, and push the long URLs to the list of references.

Comment: @cfr Sorry I'm pretty new. I know how to use `\cite` and such but could you detail the other two or all three in an answer? I'm just not completely sure how to approach that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of adding the source in the cpation, I would add it below the picture. Also, for typesetting the urls, it is better to use `url` package so that you need not escape underscores with backslashes.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{ampicillin_timeline}\par
  (\footnotesize\url{https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Penicillin_spheroplast_generation.svg})
  \caption{Illustration of ampicillin inhibiting bacterial formation.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just to for thoroughness, although I like @HarishKumars answer more, this worked for my original intentions:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{ampicillin_timeline}
  \caption{Illustration of ampicillin inhibiting bacterial formation.
    (https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Penicillin\_spheroplast\_%
    generation.svg)}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```